# Check with log strout received from fluentd forwarder using fluentd aggregator

Tags: kubernetes, logging, fluentd, aggregator

1. In the k8s environment, fluentd is running in daemonset format, so the pod mounted the fluent.conf file as configmap. Below is the contents of the conf file. Collect logs starting with calico-node and send them as output (this is normally done with the k logs command. I checked to see if it came out as output) and 192.168.123.230 (it is in the same band as the cluster, so ping works from the pod). The server is a single server with fluentd, the aggregator, on its own.
   Therefore, logs must be sent from the daemon pod to the aggregator.

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/containers/calico-node*.log
  tag kube.kubeproxy
  <parse>
        @type json
  </parse>
</source>


<match kube.kubeproxy>
    @type forward
    send_timeout 60s
    recover_wait 10s
    hard_timeout 60s

    <server>
      host 192.168.123.230
      port 24224
    </server>
</match>

<match kube.kubeproxy>
  @type stdout
</match>


## And below is the aggregator setting that outputs the log received from the pod to stdout.
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
</source>

<match kube.kubeproxy>
  @type stdout
  @id output_stdout
</match>
~

........................................................i tried above process
```

Where did I make a mistake? To stdout, the aggregator does not do stdout.